# Dragging to reposition or resize controls in design view not behaving with a smooth effect

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form which holds a few textboxes and labels. I am trying to improve the design of the form in design view but:

When I copy and paste a control in the same form, the control jumps to a different section.

When I drag to reposition the control the control, the control moves without precision. The dragging is not smooth at all.

When I resize the control, it either over expands and over shrinks. The action is not smooth at all.

I have only been able to reposition and resize the controls by using their `left` and `width` properties. Has someone come across this before? I am using Access 2016.

Comment: Happens only on this one form? Might have to rebuild form. Sometimes weirdness is due to corruption that can't be fixed otherwise.

Comment: @June7 yes it happens only on this form. Such a weird thing. Do you know if this happens only in the  2016 version? If so, I may have to upgrade as it's not the first time.

Comment: I use 2010. I don't remember ever having this issue. If this has happened before, might try reinstall Access.

Comment: If this form only, rebuild it.

Comment: This may be a bug in access 2016. Since  i get it from time to time. Rebuilding the forms fixed the problem.